# Unhandled exception at 0x6BE20E11 (ucrtbased.dll) in labs.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000004D

Tags: c++

It looks like there are bugs in my function makeUpper. I have tried pointer and some other ways, but it didn't work. And here are what in the sorting.txt :

```
Michigan

Montana

New York
Alabama

WYOMING

South Carolina

mISSISSIPPI

Iowa

ohio
```

My aim is to make all the letters in upper cases and listing them in alphabetic order.
Please help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
void bubblesort(char line[][30], int n);
void swapStrings(char *first[], char *second[]);
void makeUpper(char first[][30], char upperFirst[][30]);

int main()
{
    char state[NUM][30];
    char upper[NUM][30];
    int i, nspot;
    FILE* infile;

    /*Read file into first array.*/
    infile = fopen("sorting.txt", "r");
    if (infile == 0)
    {
        printf("trouble opening file.\n");
        return(0);
    }

    i = 0;
    while ((fgets(state[i], 30, infile)) != NULL)
    {
        nspot = strlen(state[i]) - 1;
        if (state[i][nspot] == '\n')
            state[i][nspot] = '\0'; 
        i++;
    }

    makeUpper(state, upper);

    bubblesort(upper, NUM);

    for (i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", upper[i]);
    }

    fclose(infile);

    return 0;
}


void bubblesort(char line[][30], int n)
{
    int last;
    int i;

    for (last = n - 1; last >= 1; last--)
        for (i = 0; i <= last - 1; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(line[i], line[i + 1]) > 0)
            swapStrings(&line[i], &line[i + 1]);
        }
}

void swapStrings(char* first[], char* second[])
{
    char swap[30];

    strcpy(swap, first);
    strcpy(first, second);
    strcpy(second, swap);
}

void makeUpper(char first[][30], char upperFirst[][30])
{
    int i,j;
    int test;

    for (i = 0; i < NUM; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < (strlen(first[i])); j++)
        {
            if (first[i][j] > 90)
                strcpy(upperFirst[i][j], toupper(first[i][j]));
            else
                strcpy(upperFirst[i][j], first[i][j]);
        }
        upperFirst[i][strlen(first[i])] = '\0';
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't put tags on your post that aren't appropriate. Please **do** spend enough time to reduce your problem to a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

`strcpy(upperFirst[i][j], toupper(first[i][j]));`

you need this:

`upperFirst[i][j] = toupper(first[i][j]);`